# How do I auto-populate info on a master sheet when adding a new tab in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, auto-populate

I am making a [master project tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQdRHgQFvnq0NOXxQS_uVDLouhN01fA5_DCQfpIddYM/edit#gid=0) in google sheets that has multiple project plans. Each project plan has its own tab and I have a master view tab that currently vlookups information from each project plan (owner, status, start date, end date etc.) and displays it on the master view tab.

What I am trying to do is duplicate a project plan tab in the sheet, rename the tab, and have the new project plan name and same vlookup information populate on the master view tab. I figure I need to be querying the sheet as opposed to vlookup, but I'm unsure of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({'Project Plan 1'!A2:G; 'Project Plan 2'!A2:G}, 
 "select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 
  where Col3 matches '[A-Z ]+'", 0)
```

[image]

```
{'Project Plan 1'!A2:G; 'Project Plan 2'!A2:G} - array of sheets/tabs 
separated by semicolon ; ...all ranges needs to have same amount of columns


'[A-Z ]+' - regex expression to focus on caps characters of range 
from A to Z and empty space space in any order and any amount
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE BELOW:

There is no good way to make this happen automatically. This is one of the most commonly asked questions in Google Sheets help forums.

Google Sheets are designed to collect data ALL in ONE tab and disaggregate it into reports on other tabs using Filters, Query's and other sophisticated formulas for SUMMARIZING data based on year or month or "project".

MS Excel is designed completely the opposite way. To collect data on MANY tabs and aggregate that data in one "master" tab.  This is because in Excel, it would otherwise be difficult to sum things up by year, or month, or "project" if they weren't in separate tabs.

Is there any reason you couldn't set up to collect data for ALL your projects on the same tab like this:

[image: Flat Database]